# what is the difference between use of var_dump() and mage::log() to debug?

Tags: log, debug

I mean when i can use var_dump() and mage::log().

I have some idea about log. if we enable log settings and for example if we use mage::log($obj).it will print $obj information in system.log file.

where as var_dump() print direclty in browser.

Please comment if i'm anything wrong.

Comment: No one mentioned this,but I don't feel it deserves its own answer...`var_dump()` can cause "Headers already sent" exceptions in some cases, so be careful with using that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`var_dump()` shows the information in your browser.
`Mage::log()` echos information to your system.log file (`var/log/system.log`).

To use `Mage::log()`, you need to enable logging in the backend: System > Configuration > Developer -> Log Settings -> Enabled > Set to "Yes".

Furthermore you can force logging using the forth parameter of `Mage::log()` set to true:
`Mage::log($foo,null,'system.log',true);`

According to the function in Mage.php:
`public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)`

`Mage::log()` will be especially useful if you do not see the output in your browser (debugging SOAP API requests, AJAX requests,...).

Comment: If i run my observer https://paste.ofcode.org/37ccujDxcru9uDgYkE2PMiy   my log file name 35 instead of event.log, may i know what is the issue? screenshot -> https://snipboard.io/62r8hA.jpg @Anna Völkl thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are right.

var_dump() will print in your browser, so it can only be used when you debug locally.

In contrast, Mage::log() prints to a log file. So you can use Mage::log() even on production systems, since you can view the output "hidden" from the user.

Answer (score 1):

output buffering:

`ob_start(); var_dump($object_var_array); $dump= ob_get_clean();
Mage::log( "**dumping: {$dump}", null, 'mydumped.log' );`

I use this when I need to find something on a live site and do not want to be printing a bunch of garbage to the screen. I would not leave it on for all time, just for testing..

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding another advantage of mage::log() over var_dump().

for example saveBillingAction() method in  onepagecontroller.php

```
      $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            Mage::log($data);//it's  working perfectly
var_dump($data);//its not working.(i don't know exact reason.i think ajax calls)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log variable information, you can use `Mage::log(print_r($var, true))` as well.

Also, you can specify your own log files in Mage::log.  Generally when I'm debugging I output to a log file specific to the module.  `Mage::log('Something', null, 'mylog.log')`

Answer (score 0):

var_dump / print_r can only provide reasonably meaningful/trackable information when you work on templates. It'll royally screw up forwarding however and Magento uses that extensively.