# Loading Custom Blocks and Layouts

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, ce-1.9.2.2

I'm new to Magento. I'm learning to add custom Module.
I have created a custom module and able to load the controller. 
Now i'm learning to add Blocks and Layouts. I have added the files but i'm not getting the expected output.

I have used namespace 'Nikhil' and the Module name is 'MyModule'.

When it's executed, I can see the webpage, there are no errors. But its not showing the string "MyModule Block" or its not logging the message 'i'm in Block'.

I have spend several hours debugging it. Please help

The contents of the configuration file in `\test\app\etc\modules\Nikhil_MyMdoule.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nikhil_MyModule>        
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Nikhil_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Config File: `app\code\local\Nikhil\MyModule\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nikhil_MyModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Nikhil_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Nikhil_MyModule</module>
                    <frontName>nikhil</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
         </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Nikhil_MyModule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Controller: `app\code\local\Nikhil\MyModule\controllers\IndexController.php`

```
    class Nikhil_MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            Mage::log('im in Controller');
            $this->loadLayout(); 
            $this->renderLayout();
            Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        }

        public function testAction(){
            echo "custom function";
        }
    }
```

Block file: `app\code\local\Nikhil\MyModule\Block\MyBlock.php`

```
class Nikhil_MyModule_Block_MyBlock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction(){
        Mage::log('im in Block');
        return "MyModule Block";
    }
}
```

Sorry missed to add following files.

\app\design\frontend\base\layout\mymodule.xml

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<mymodule_index_index>
<reference name="content">
<block name="myblock" template="mymodule/mymodule.phtml" type="mymodule/myblock"/>
</reference>
</mymodule_index_index>
</layout>
</code>
```

And from \app\design\frontend\base\template\mymodule.phtml

```
echo $this->myfunction();
```

I'm trying to call the index Action

Comment: Which action are you looking access in the controller index or test? And can you post the content of your layout update - mymodule.xml

Comment: You need to define layout file and add your block in to it for your controller handler. In your config.xml it seems mymodule.xml

Comment: The method `myfunction()` is nowhere called. This should typically be called in a template. Can you add the contents of the `mymodule.xml` layout file and the contents of your template (`.phtml` file)?

Comment: I'm trying to call indexAction. I have created a layout file and put it in \app\design\frontend\base\layout\mymodule.xml. I have edited the question to add the details. And also created a phtml which i have put in app\design\frontend\base\template\mymodule.phtml

Comment: Put it here .app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\mymodule.xml and template file in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\mymodule.phtml

Comment: @ Rohit Did that but still not working

Comment: @nikhil Clear cache or disable them and then check

Comment: The Cache is already disabled. This there any issue with the configurations. One more question it should show the text "MyModule Block" in the page , which is returned from the block right?

Comment: Yes. it means its working now

Comment: Actually i can see the page but there is not text is not printing and also the logging is also not working. Follwoing the is the output that i get from dump `array(5) {
  [0] => string(7) "default"
  [1] => string(13) "STORE_default"
  [2] => string(26) "THEME_frontend_rwd_default"
  [3] => string(20) "mymodule_index_index"
  [4] => string(18) "customer_logged_in"
}`

Comment: Use like this `Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');`

Comment: Check here for details : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/what-is-the-difference-between-use-of-var-dump-and-magelog-to-debug

Comment: Note: logging is disabled in default installation and won't write any output unless you activated developer mode; add a fourth `true` parameter to `Mage::log()` to temporarily force logging; it becomes: `Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log', true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, enable logging from the admin, and see if it produces any files inside "var/log" folder. If not, there might be some permission issues on the folder.

Now, back to your problem, your layout file is telling Magento to search for the template file `mymodule/mymodule.phtml`, so if you are going with the base theme folder, path for your template file will be `app\design\frontend\base\template\mymodule\mymodule.phtml`.

Comment: Thanks that resolved the issue... There was slight change in the path. app\design\frontend\base\default\template\mymodule\mymodule.phtml.I wanted to up up vote you. But since i do not have enough reputation i can't. I but i will do it once i have the reputation. Thanks again